# How do I check if there is a selection?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I have a NSTextView and I need to check if there is a selection, (blue highlight) of a word (or anything really), and not just a cursor. How can I do this. `nil` doesn't work, and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[NSTextView selectedRanges]` method to see if there is a selection.

```
if (self.textView.selectedRanges.count > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Some text is selected!");
}
```

You may want to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/selectedRanges) for more information.

Comment: This is incorrect. If there is just an insertion point then `selectedRanges` returns a single range with a `length` of `0`.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple selection in an `NSTextView`, the methods `selectedRanges` returns an array of all the selections. If there is just a cursor this method returns a single `NSRange` with the `location` giving where the cursor is and the `length` set to zero.

So your question can be answer with:

```
NSArray *allSelections = myTextView.selectedRanges;
BOOL hasSelection = allSelections.count > 1
                 || (allSelections.count == 1 && allSelections[0].length != 0);
```

HTH